# how to overwrite the value of a variable in c

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Here I want to change the change the value of **i** but getting error as:
**error: redefinition of 'i'
int i=4;
^
exp.c:5:9: note: previous definition is here
int i=4;**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void){
    int i=4;
    printf("before:%i",i);
    
    int i=5;
    printf("after:%i",i);
    
    
}
```

So my question is how to overwrite the value of a variable which already value assigned.

Comment: I would suggest you to find [a good book about C programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) and start studying the language before attempting to write any code.

Comment: You're welcome, another good list of books is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: I wonder how helpful coding community is and once again Thank you very  much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may *define* a variable only once.

You can (usually!) (re)assign a value to a variable as many times as you want:

```
int main(void){
    int i=4;     // Declare as "int" and assign value "4"
    printf("before:%i",i);
    
    i=5;  // Assign a different value
    printf("after:%i",i);
}
```